# Warning: static method should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java

I am learning Java and I am planning to create a calculator Java applet which has the function of adding, dividing, multiplying and reset. Got some warning sign that:

> The static method valueOf(double) from the type String should be accessed in a static way

The calculator is working though. But kindly seek your expertise on how this warning sign could be avoided and what improvement i could made to the coding.

CalEngine class which include listener, maths function.

```
public class CalEngine implements ActionListener{

    Calculator parent;
    double current=0;
    double prevnum=0;
    double totalnum=0;
    int funct=0;
    String equalnum;
    public CalEngine(Calculator parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();
    String  cbuttonlabel = src.getText();
    if(cbuttonlabel.equals("+"))
        {       clearscreen();
                funct = 1;      }
    else if(cbuttonlabel.equals("-"))
    {       clearscreen();
            funct = 2;          }
    else if(cbuttonlabel.equals("/"))
    {       clearscreen();
            funct = 3;          }
    else if(cbuttonlabel.equals("="))
    {   equal();                }
    else if(cbuttonlabel.equals("Reset"))
    {   prevnum = 0;
        current = 0;
        totalnum =0;
        clearscreen();
    }
    else
        {
        prevnum = current;
        current = Double.parseDouble(cbuttonlabel);
        parent.setScreen(cbuttonlabel);
        }
    }

    private void equal() {
        if(funct == 1)
        {
            add();
        }
        else if(funct == 2)
        {
            minus();
        }
        else if(funct == 3)
        {
            divide();
        }
        parent.setScreen(equalnum.valueOf(totalnum));
        totalnum =0;
    }

    private void minus() {
        totalnum = prevnum-current;}

    private void divide() {
        totalnum = prevnum/current; }

    private void clearscreen() {
        parent.setScreen("");   }

    private void add() {
        totalnum = current + prevnum;
    }

}



Calculator UI

public class Calculator {

    JPanel ova;
    JPanel pan;
    JTextField screen;
    JButton b1;
    JButton b2;
    JButton b3;
    JButton b4;
    JButton b5;
    JButton b6;
    JButton b7;
    JButton b8;
    JButton b9;
    JButton b0;
    JButton bplus;
    JButton bequal;
    JButton bminus;
    JButton bdivide;
    JButton breset;

    Calculator(){

        ova = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout(); 
        ova.setLayout(bl);

        screen = new JTextField(300);
        ova.add("North",screen);

        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b3 = new JButton("3");
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b9 = new JButton("9");
        b0 = new JButton("0");
        bplus = new JButton("+");
        bequal = new JButton("=");
        bminus = new JButton("-");
        bdivide = new JButton("/");
        breset = new JButton("Reset");

        pan = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(5,3);
        pan.setLayout(gl);

        pan.add(b1);
        pan.add(b2);
        pan.add(b3);
        pan.add(b4);
        pan.add(b5);
        pan.add(b6);
        pan.add(b7);
        pan.add(b8);
        pan.add(b9);
        pan.add(b0);
        pan.add(bplus);
        pan.add(bequal);
        pan.add(bminus);
        pan.add(bdivide);
        pan.add(breset);        

        ova.add("Center",pan);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Calculator");

        jf.setContentPane(ova);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(500,500);

        CalEngine calcEngine = new CalEngine(this);
        b0.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b1.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b2.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b3.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b4.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b5.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b6.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b7.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b8.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        b9.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        bplus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        bequal.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        bminus.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        bdivide.addActionListener(calcEngine);
        breset.addActionListener(calcEngine);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Calculator();

    }


    public void setScreen(String wee) {

        screen.setText(wee);
    }

    public String getScreen() {

        return screen.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are asking for a review of your code you might be better to post it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, when using `.equals()`, it is more efficient to use single quotes for a char instead of double quotes

Comment: @GregtheIncredulous This isn't about code review - it's about how to deal with a specific warning message.  This is the right place for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the line of code in question:

```
parent.setScreen(equalnum.valueOf(totalnum));
```

You're calling the static method `valueOf` on an instance of a String object (`equalnum`). You should call it on the class itself instead.

```
parent.setScreen(String.valueOf(totalnum));
```

Comment: That was very subtle; in all my years of programming in Java, I had never run into that warning before, so I was wondering why Eclipse was complaining about my code accessing a public static constant. Turns out I was inadvertently trying to do it from an instance of the class in question instead of the class itself; proof positive that if you work with a language long enough, you will make every possible mistake there is to make in that language :)